# Custom Scss for foundations for email not importing

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, html-email

I am new to Sass and have read a lot of documentation but can't seem to override the settings file with some custom scss. I need a variety of buttons and colors so I created a _global.scss file to create new variables. I imported this into the app.scss.

I get this error when I try to run npm build:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src/assets/scss/_global.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "$hollow-margin": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ": 0 0 $global-margi"
        on line 23 of src/assets/scss/_global.scss
>> $hollow-margin: 0 0 $global-margin 0;
   ^
```

Here is the app.scss file:

```
@import 'global';
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation-emails';

@import 'template/template';
```

Here is the _global.scss file:

```
// New colors
$featured-color: #ED145B;


// 1. Hollow  Black Button
// ---------
$hollow-padding: (
  tiny: 4px 8px 4px 8px,
  small: 5px 10px 5px 10px,
  default: 8px 18px 8px 18px,
  large: 10px 20px 10px 20px,
);
$hollow-font-size: (
  tiny: 10px,
  small: 13px,
  default: 14px,
  large: 20px,
);

$hollow-color: $black;
$hollow-color-alt: $medium-gray
$hollow-background: $white;
$hollow-border: 2px solid $black;
$hollow-radius: $global-radius;
$hollow-rounded: $global-rounded;

// 1. Transparent Button
// ---------
$transparent-padding: (
  tiny: 4px 8px 4px 8px,
  small: 5px 10px 5px 10px,
  default: 8px 18px 8px 18px,
  large: 10px 20px 10px 20px,
);
$transparent-font-size: (
  tiny: 10px,
  small: 12px,
  default: 14px,
  large: 20px,
);

$transparent-color: $white;
$transparent-color-alt: $medium-gray
$transparent-background: none;
$transparent-border: 2px solid $white;
$transparent-radius: 2px;
$transparent-rounded: $global-rounded;

// 3. rounded grey Button
// ---------
$rounded-padding: (
  tiny: 4px 8px 4px 8px,
  small: 5px 10px 5px 10px,
  default: 8px 18px 8px 18px,
  large: 10px 20px 10px 20px,
);
$rounded-font-size: (
  tiny: 10px,
  small: 12px,
  default: 14px,
  large: 20px,
);

$rounded-color: #9B9B9B;
$rounded-color-alt: $light-gray
$rounded-background: #ED145B;
$rounded-border: 6px solid #ED145B;
$rounded-radius: $global-radius;
$rounded-rounded: $global-rounded;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is recommended that you modify the global CSS settings in the /.../[project]/src/assets/_settings.scss file for what you are trying to do. For example, that's where I changed the value of $primary_color to what I wanted to be used for the email.

Comment: Thank you, I did change the primary color but the problem is I want to change the background color, outline color, and font color so not sure wha the best way to do tis is.

Comment: Is it possible that because you imported your global.scss file first in app.scss, your settings are being overridden by the other files that are imported afterwards?